# Why does vala complain about a missing property when there is such prop

Tags: gtk, vala, gobject

I am developing a GUI app with gtk 3 and vala.
This is my source code from MainWindow::MainWindow()

```
    var menu = new MenuModel();
    var app = this.application;
    app.menubar = menu;
```

valac gives this errors :

```
ewns_viewer.vala:54.9-54.19: error: The name `menubar' does not exist in the context of `Gtk.Application'
        app.menubar = menu;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looking at [this](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Application), says otherwise.
I also tried

```
var obj_class = (ObjectClass) typeof (Gtk.Application).class_ref ();
var properties = obj_class.list_properties ();
foreach (var prop in properties) 
{
    stdout.printf ("%s\n", prop.name);
}
```

That gives this output :

```
application-id
flags
is-registered
is-remote
inactivity-timeout
action-group
register-session
app-menu
menubar
```

If I get it right Gtk.Application has all that properties,so why does valac give me this error?

I am using valac 0.14.2.Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding in `/usr/share/vala-0.14/vapi/gtk+-3.0.vapi` is out of date for Vala 0.14 on Ubuntu. If you install Vala 0.16, this binding will be available.

Answer (score 0):

That property was added in vala 0.15.1. You are using a six-month-old release of vala. The latest release is 0.17.1, released a week ago.